# Redirection stdout with low level api in C

Tags: c, operating-system

Is there a way to redirect stdout with low level API... haven't found a function or a way to actually do this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dup` system call should let you redirect stdout, as shown in [this example](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:dup).

`freopen` also will work, if you're redirecting to a file, but `dup` can also be used 
with pipes and sockets.

Comment: YES!  Mad touch-typing skills FTW!

Answer (score 3):

I believe dup2(fd,1) does the trick, e.g. after opening fd using open().

Comment: If you have a variable `FILE* f`, you can get the fd with `fileno(f)`. Something like this: `dup2(fileno(f), 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, never known how to mix up `FILE*` and regular `fd`s. I presume mixing them up in I/O is a recipe for disaster? (i.e. `FILE*` functions not knowing about your lower-level access to the `fd`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `freopen()` to redirect it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `freopen()` to redirect stdout to a file. If you're using a posix-like system, you can use `close()`, `dup()` and `open()`, though these work with file descriptors and not FILEs.